improt tensorflow: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
My progress:
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\wu\\anaconda3\\envs\\python3.7\\Lib\\site-packages")
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
print("TensorFlow version:", tf.__version__)
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

When I run the code in teminal, get an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wu\anaconda3\envs\python3.7\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 62, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *                                                             
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: 找不到指定的模块。

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\MyselfProjects\PycharmProjects\dynamic_schedule_flexible_job_shop\tardiness_earliness_job_arrival\jjj.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\wu\anaconda3\envs\python3.7\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\wu\anaconda3\envs\python3.7\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\wu\anaconda3\envs\python3.7\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 77, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wu\anaconda3\envs\python3.7\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 62, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: 找不到指定的模块。


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors for some common causes and solutions.
If you need help, create an issue at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues and include the entire stack trace above this error message.


However, right-clicking run works fine.
enter image description here

my env(anaconda virtual env which it's newly created):


python:3.7
tensorflow-gpu:2.6
system:window10
cpu: Intel Core i9-10900K
GPU: GeForce RTX 2080Ti


Already install VC_redist.x64.exe before installing tensorflow-gpu.
'C:\Windows\System32' exit msvcp140_1.dll.
Want to detect which DLL is missing. Dependency Walker tool dose not support win10.
my expect:
How to detect which DLL is missing.


Looks like you're launching 2 different VEnvs (C:\Users\wu\anaconda3\envs\python3.7 and C:\Users\wu\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_python3.7).

Hi @hui shi,This error can occur due to missing or incompatible DLLs. Here's how you can diagnose the missing DLL:1.Make sure TensorFlow is properly installed in your virtual environment.While Dependency Walker doesn't fully support Windows 10, 2.you can still use it to check for missing DLLs. You can try running Dependency Walker in compatibility mode for an earlier version of Windows.3.Ensure that the directory containing the required DLLs is included in the system's PATH environment variable. TensorFlow may require specific versions of DLLs to be available in the PATH.

If all else fails, consider reinstalling TensorFlow in your virtual environment to ensure a clean installation.
